# Как проверить, какая картинка в image?

Tags: delphi

```
 if image1.Picture='sprite\gun1.png' then
```

Типы не совпадают (стринг и имэйдж). Как тогда проверить, какая картинка в image1?

Comment: Во-первых, насколько я знаю, класс TIMAGE не умеет работать с PNG.

Comment: Это библиотека такая.

Answer (score 1):

Советую не смотреть в сторону TImage. Вы же наверняка загружаете в Image картинку, используя opendialog ? Так вот, когда загружаете, просто заведите переменную и записывайте в неё имя загруженного файла, а затем сверяйте =)

Answer (score 0):

Проверить можно по имени класса:

- `TImage` - bmp
- `TPNGImage` - png
- `TJpegImage` - jpeg